# Android ListFragment: How to enable the Lollipop "Ripple Effect"?

Tags: android, material-design

I have an Activity with an ListFragment inside it (to support my tablet-layout, but thats not important).

Now I want to enable the ripple effect for the ListFragment. For example in another activity, I just use an normal ListView and it works there automaticly.

How is that possible in a easy way?

Example (not for an ListFragment but you'll get the point)
[image]

Comment: are we talking about pre-Lollipop or from Lollipop on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to define an extra ripple effect. If you want to activate the standard ripple effect on API 21+ apply

```
android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
```

on the list item. This will provide the same selector-like effect on pre-API 21 devices just without the ripple.

Answer (score 4):

## API 21+

In Lollipop you can set your views background to a [RippleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html) which you can define in XML.

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@android:color/white"> <!-- ripple color -->

    <item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/> <!-- normal color -->

</ripple>
```

Then set your view's background to `android:background="@drawable/my_ripple"`

## Pre-API 21

For a solution that can be back-ported to older versions of Android, the following [number of open source libraries](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/167) are available that offer this functionality.

Comment: Just for 21+, I'll try out your sollution, thanks :)